# Xamarin Android 11 out of memory error, when camera takes pictures

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

The Xamarin app runs smoothly on Android 10.
When transferred to Android 11 and Lenovo Tablet, on talking photos gives the error

*"phone available memory is not enough.Temporarily cannot take pictures"*

I use this as a folder to store camera data. I use Xam.Plugin.Media for photos.

*string folder = Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data", packageName, "files/Pictures/");*

But it has 128 GB free.Restart is the only solution.

Memory is empty, it takes 5 pictures and crashes with the above memory error. It doesn't look like picture size problem.

Working smoothly on Android 10 , stopped on Android 11.

I deleted all the app files. Same problem

Comment: What generates the error?  Is it a runtime exception?  A console log message?  Or something else?  Is that the verbatim error message?

Comment: You can try to run the app using a different machine，then see if it still occurs error.

Answer (score 0):

well
The problem seems to be at the default camera app, as it freezes with the same message when working alone.
I use xam.media for taking and saving photos.(jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)

So the solution is
use a camera addon to use instead of default camera. (any ideas?)
or
force my app to use Open Camera. any ideas how?